# Upload and retrieve image using parse and back4app with nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform, back4app

Maybe this is an already answered question but I can't seem to find the right answer for me. I can't see what's wrong with my code.

I have a form to upload the specifics of a vehicle such as route, price, a picture of the vehicle, etc. When I get the url of the image, it doesn't display anything
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyxz7.png)

Here's the code I use to post my form

```
 //POST create vehicle
    app.post('/createVehicle', async function(req, res, next){


     const fileData = new Parse.File("VehiclePic", { base64: req.body.VehicleImg }, "image/png");
     console.log(fileData);

    let car = new Car();

    const Vehicle = {
        VehicleImg: fileData,
        Name: req.body.Name,
        description: req.body.description,
        Price: parseInt(req.body.Price),
        Route: req.body.Route,
        PassengerAmount: parseInt(req.body.PassengerAmount)
    }


    try{
        fileData.save().then(saved => {

            car.set('Image', saved);
            car.set('Name', Vehicle.Name);
            car.set('Description', Vehicle.description);
            car.set('Route', Vehicle.Route);
            car.set('Price', Vehicle.Price);
            car.set('PassengerAmount', Vehicle.PassengerAmount);

            console.log("URL vehiculo " + saved.url());
            car.save();

            console.log("El vehiculo ha sido creado con exito!");
        })     

    }catch(error){
        console.error('error ' , error);
    }

    res.redirect('/');

});
```

The reason I don't use Vehicle.VehicleImg is because it returns me an undefined object.

Here's the code to get all data

```
const Car = Parse.Object.extend('Vehicle');
const query = new Parse.Query(Car);

app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
const VehicleInfo = [];

query.notEqualTo("objectId", null);
try {
    const result = await query.find();
    result.forEach(vehicle => {
        const vehiclePic = vehicle.get('Image');
        VehicleInfo.push({
            VehicleID: vehicle.id,
            VehicleImage: vehiclePic,
            VehicleName: vehicle.get('Name'),
            Description: vehicle.get('Description'),
            Price: vehicle.get('Price'),
            Rating: vehicle.get('Rating'),
            Route: vehicle.get('Route'),
            PassengerAmount: vehicle.get('PassengerAmount')
        });

    });

    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MainPage',
        VehicleData: VehicleInfo

    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('error fetching objects', error);
}
});
```

EDIT:this is the form, I'm using ejs.

```
<div class="createVehicle-section container">
            <br>

            <form method="POST" action="/createVehicle" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div id="img">
                    <label for="VehicleImg">Seleccione la imagen:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="VehicleImg" name="VehicleImg" >
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="col-lg-12 row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="VehicleName">Nombre del vehiculo</label>
                        <input type="text" id="VehicleName" name="Name">
                        <br>
                        <label for="DescriptionVe">Descripción</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Descriptionve" name="description">
                    </div>          

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="PriceVe">Precio</label>
                        <input type="number" id="PriceVe" name="Price" min="0" max="9999">
                        <br>
                        <label for="RouteVe">Ruta</label>
                        <input type="text" id="RouteVe" name="Route">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-6 container">
                    <label for="PassegerAmountVe">Cantidad de Pasajeros Permitida</label>
                    <input type="number" id="PassengerAmountVe" name="PassengerAmount" min="0" max="9999">
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-main btn-lg btn-shadow" type="submit" value="Guardar"/>

                </div>

            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Here's my multer code to upload it to a localstorage, and I need to upload it to back4app.

```
//Multer Image Storage 
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/images/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){ //cb = callback
         cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
// Init Upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fieldSize: 1000000},
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
}).single('VehicleImg');
```

Comment: Can you inspect what kind of data you have at `req.body.VehicleImg`? Is it really base64? Also, try to add the extension to the file name when saving.

Comment: It says it's a string. I don't know if it helps but in my form I didn't add the enctype="multipart/form-data", if I add that it says it cannot parse that data because it appears undefined.

Comment: Can you please share the code of your form?

Comment: Done, hope this can help in some way.

Comment: Do you have any middleware in place to handle the multipart form data? You will need something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload#readme)

Comment: I was using multer to upload the image but to a local folder in my project and if possible I would like to store it directly in my back4app directory, I'm kinda new using multer, parse and back4app

Comment: Can you share your code in which you try to use the multer? It should work.

Comment: It works, but as I said I need to upload it directly to back4app and I don't know how to set the destination to that database.

Comment: I've just sent you a suggestion using multer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
const upload = multer();

app.post('/createVehicle', upload.single('VehicleImg'), async function(req, res, next){

     const fileData = new Parse.File("VehiclePic.png", [...req.file.buffer], "image/png");
     console.log(fileData);

    let car = new Car();

    const Vehicle = {
        VehicleImg: fileData,
        Name: req.body.Name,
        description: req.body.description,
        Price: parseInt(req.body.Price),
        Route: req.body.Route,
        PassengerAmount: parseInt(req.body.PassengerAmount)
    }


    try{
        fileData.save().then(saved => {

            car.set('Image', saved);
            car.set('Name', Vehicle.Name);
            car.set('Description', Vehicle.description);
            car.set('Route', Vehicle.Route);
            car.set('Price', Vehicle.Price);
            car.set('PassengerAmount', Vehicle.PassengerAmount);

            console.log("URL vehiculo " + saved.url());
            car.save();

            console.log("El vehiculo ha sido creado con exito!");
        })     

    }catch(error){
        console.error('error ' , error);
    }

    res.redirect('/');

});
```

Comment: (node:59536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data. I did console.log(req.file.buffer) and this is what it was displayed <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 a8 00 00 02 66 08 06 00 00 00 90 5a 72 98 00 00 00 04 73 42 49 54 08 08 08 08 7c 08 64 88 00 ... 331535 more bytes>

Comment: I've just updated the answer. Try `const fileData = new Parse.File("VehiclePic.png", [...req.file.buffer], "image/png");`

Comment: Thank you sir, now it works perfectly, what does the [...] mean or do?

Comment: It basically transforms the buffer to an array of bytes (which is the format that Parse JS SDK expects to receive).